# Analog Vom and AC reading

Tags: electrical

I have a surplus 120/240vac generator that has a problem with AC voltage invading the DC control circuit. The invading voltage is erractic. My Fluke 86-5 digital meter is to slow to accurately read fast moving voltage. It's useless to track and view this voltage. I tried a Simpson 260 but it does not have the capability to block DC while on the AC position. And it does not read frequency. So does anyone have a suggestion of a good analog meter that can read what I need to see?

Comment: That sounds like a **ground fault**.  That's going to be a serious problem for the usability of that generator, it is surely electrifying the chassis of the generator, and the windings may be internally burnt up. Or they are just heavily contaminated.  You can try tearing down the generator and cleaning it up.  Perfect world you'd VPI but that's probably not in the budget, at least clean it up with some Glyptal.  Now you know why it's surplus!

Comment: I agree with JWH20 on both the scope and a cap to read dc with your meter. I have rebuilt a couple of old military surplus gensets. Most were older than I am and the capacitors were shorting out (long since dried out electrolytic) replacing them and a couple of diodes was a majority of the problems electronically. The other problems were mechanical and cleaning and lubing were all it took. Today I wish I would not have sold them because those little 4 cylinder motors were so smooth.

Answer (score 2):

You need an oscilloscope for this, not a meter.

Meters "average" either electronically or mechanically.  If, however, you simply need to block DC while trying to measure a superimposed AC, just use a capacitor in series with the signal.  The cap will block any DC and will allow AC through.  Since the input impedance on a meter is relatively high, you just need to choose a capacitor that has a high enough voltage rating and a high enough capacitance so that it's effective resistance is small compared to the input impedance of the meter if you are wanting to get a precise AC voltage measurement.

Comment: I am using a diode to block the DC. I know it's only half voltage. This is not a ground fault. The generator works perfectly fine for emergency back up. 60 Hertz and 240 volt steady. Load changes and voltage regulation well in it's operating function. You would never know there was a problem. It was only until I installed a remote start with WiFi did I notice a problem. The AC of  approximately 55 volts in the DC control circuit is causing the remote start to latch the preheaters. I have nerrowed it down to the exciter circuit. And will trace it again when the temperature gets above freezing.